# Evaluating Complex Integrals with the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I'm quite new to complex analysis and have this question:

Evaluate $\ \int_C \bar z dz$, where C is the unit circle in a counterclockwise direction

What I have done is: 
$$\ \int_C \bar z dz = \int_0^{2\pi} \overline {e^{it}}. ie^{it}dt = \int_0^{2\pi}  {e^{-it}}. ie^{it}dt = \int_0^{2\pi}idt $$
$$\ =2\pi i$$

Is this right or have I gone wrong somewhere, I think this seems too straightforward?

Comment: It is correct and yes it is that straightforward.  Basically your first equality is simply applying the definition of the path integral.  Then it is just calculus.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your computation is correct.

Note that if $\gamma$ is a simple bounded regular closed curve counterclockwise oriented then
$$\int_\gamma \bar z dz=\int_\gamma (x-iy) d(x+iy)=\int_\gamma (xdx+ydy)+i\int_\gamma(xdy-ydx)\\\stackrel{GT}{=}\iint_D (0-0)dxdy+i\iint_D (1-(-1))dxdy=2i\cdot \mbox{Area}(D)$$
where we used the [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem) (GT) and $D$ is the region bounded by $\gamma$.

Comment: I was asked another question which I think follows what you're saying here:                                                                                                         Evaluate $\ \int_Cfdz$ where $\ f(z) = \frac {1}{z-3} $ and C is any simple closed curve in a counterclockwise direction with z = 3 inside C

Comment: No. This is another matter because the integrand function is $1/(z-3)$. Use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchyIntegralFormula.html with $f=1$ and $z_0=3$.

Comment: @RobertZ Ok thanks!

Comment: @Lauren Burke Any further doubt?

Comment: @user6122081 Any further doubt?

Answer (score 0):

$$
\oint_{C}\bar{z}\,\mathrm{d}z =
\oint_{C}{\bar{z}\,z \over z}\,\mathrm{d}z =
\oint_{C}{\mathrm{d}z \over z} = \
\bbox[10px,border:1px dotted navy]{\displaystyle{2\pi\,\mathrm{i}}}
$$

> Note that $\displaystyle{\bar{z}\,z = \left\vert\, z\,\right\vert^{2} = 1}$ because $\displaystyle{C}$ is the $\underline{\mbox{unit circle}}$.

Comment: Note that $z\overline{z}=|z|=1$ because of the unit circle.

Comment: @TonyS.F. Thanks. I added some text as based in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

on the unit circle $\bar{z}=\frac{1}{z}$, so $\int_{C}\bar{z} \, dz$ is $\int_{C}z^{-1} \, dz$, and it is a standard theorem in complex analysis that $\int_{C}z^{-1} \, dz$ is $2\pi i$. And, to prove $2\pi i=\int_{C}z^{-1} \, dz$, the idea would be what you just wrote above (let $z=e^{it}$) and so on.